# if suitable content with session as I have

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I need to find out about in the get_id that have been made ​​if there is a user with the name and e-mail.

the if statement must find out about the username and email match it as it came out of tablen with the get,

Problem right now:
even if username exists with get_id and his username and email, it comes out still ahead.

solved: what I want it to do it is that it should find out through session and select content about the things fit together, and if he has done this before once. and if he has done it once, he not only does it again.

```
if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT tilmeldt_navn, tilmeldt_email FROM `tilmeldtOpgave` WHERE `get_id` = ?')) { 
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
        $id = $_GET['id'];

        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($tilmeldt_navn, $tilmeldt_email);
        if($stmt->num_rows != 1){
            if($tilmeldt_navn = $_SESSION["navn"] and $tilmeldt_email = $_SESSION["mail"])
            {
                ?>
                <form action="#" method="post">
                    <input type="submit" name="tilmeld" value="Tilmeld dig!" id="tilmeldklik">
                </form>
                <?php
            }
            else
            {
                ?>
                <form action="#" method="post">
                    <input type="submit" name="frameld" value="Frameld dig!" id="frameldklik">
                </form>
                <?php
            }
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
```

Comment: 'and' should be replaced by '&&'. Also You don't need to create 3 new html elements on each state of the 'if'. You can have smth like `<form blabla> <input blabla name=$name value=$value id=$id /> </form>` so in your if/else you will assign values to $name, $value and $id

Comment: What you mean on its?